# Grouping values with Partition by query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on oracle and the data in following format,

## Sample table and data...

```
create table testd
(
  Source_id varchar2(20),
  job_status varchar2(20)
);

insert into testd testd values('ABC', 'canceled');
insert into testd testd values('ABC', 'failed');
insert into testd testd values('ABC', 'finished');
insert into testd testd values('DEF', 'canceled');
insert into testd testd values('DEF', 'failed');
insert into testd testd values('DEF', 'finished');
insert into testd testd values('DEF', 'canceled');
insert into testd testd values('DEF', 'failed');
insert into testd testd values('DEF', 'finished');
insert into testd testd values('DEF', 'canceled');
insert into testd testd values('PQR', 'failed');
insert into testd testd values('PQR', 'finished');
```

======================

I grouped columns as

```
Source_id   job_status  Count
ABC         canceled    1
ABC         failed      1
ABC         finished    1
DEF         canceled    3
DEF         failed      2
DEF         finished    2
PQR         failed      1
PQR         finished    1
```

tried with this query, but unable to achieve desired output.

```
  select Source_id, job_status,
  count(job_status) over (partition by Source_id order by Source_id desc)  as r
  from testd
```

my, expected output is, top 2 source_ids, with job status count, see example below.

e.g.

```
Source_id   job_status  Count
DEF         canceled    3
DEF         failed      2
DEF         finished    2
ABC         canceled    1
ABC         failed      1
ABC         finished    1
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `ORDER BY`:

```
select DISTINCT Source_id, job_status,
   count(job_status) over (partition by Source_id, job_status)  as r
from testd;
```

or simply:

```
SELECT Source_id, job_status, COUNT(*)
FROM testd
GROUP BY Source_Id, job_status;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8dd1f947f6e6870327ec46fbd2a29984)**

Comment: yes that works,
second thing I'm looking is top 2 source_ids, with job status count,

Answer (score 0):

I tried with below, Any other solution to this would be really appreciated.

```
select source_id, job_status, count(*)
from testd
where Source_Id in ( select source_id from 
                                  (
                                      SELECT source_id, COUNT(job_status) Res 
                                      from testd
                                      group by source_id
                                      order by res desc
                                  )  
                                  where rownum <= 2
               )
group by  source_id, job_status
order by source_id
```